# Count number of times value appears in columns

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, oledb, corruption

Due to some strange circumstances, random long text fields in my Microsoft Access database appear to be corrupting and being replaced with "################". I want to be able to count the number of corrupted fields with an SQL query so that I can quickly check if the number has changed.

I have written a query that can count the number of records with corrupted values, but not the total fields (e.g if 5 records have 13 corrupted values, I can get the number 5 but I want the total number of 13). How can I adjust my query?

```
SELECT Count(*) AS [Number of Errors] 
FROM GPInformation 
WHERE Profile="################" 
   OR Notes="################" 
   OR CriminalConvictionsNotes="################" 
   OR HealthIssueNotes="################" 
   OR NextOfKinAddress="################"
```

Output:

[image: output screenshot of microsoft access]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add conditional logic to the `select`:

```
SELECT (sum(iif(Profile = "################", 1, 0)) +
        sum(iif(Notes = "################", 1, 0)) +
        sum(iif(CriminalConvictionsNotes = "################", 1, 0)) +
        sum(iif(HealthIssueNotes = "################", 1, 0)) +
        sum(iif(NextOfKinAddress = "################", 1, 0))
       ) AS NumBadValues        
FROM GPInformation 
WHERE Profile = "################" OR
      Notes = "################" OR
      CriminalConvictionsNotes = "################" OR
      HealthIssueNotes = "################" OR
      NextOfKinAddress = "################";
```

Comment: worked like a charm! there were some missing parentheses so I've suggested an edit to your post

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way by `unpivoting` the data

```
SELECT Count(error_data) AS [Number of Errors] 
FROM   (SELECT 1 AS error_Data 
        FROM   gpinformation 
        WHERE  profile = "################" 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM   gpinformation 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM   gpinformation 
        WHERE  notes = "################" 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM   gpinformation 
        WHERE  criminalconvictionsnotes = "################" 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM   gpinformation 
        WHERE  healthissuenotes = "################" 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM   gpinformation 
        WHERE  nextofkinaddress = "################") A
```

Comment: Hmm...this gives a result of 704 errors, which isnt possible as there are 5 records with errors and we are only considering 5 fields for each record....

Comment: can you post those 5 records as  sample data

Comment: I would love to, but the data is private. Sorry! Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the query as follows:

```
SELECT SUM( 
   IIf(Profile="################", 1, 0) +
   IIf(Notes="################", 1, 0) +
   IIf(CriminalConvictionsNotes="################", 1, 0) +
   IIf(HealthIssueNotes="################", 1, 0) + 
   IIf(NextOfKinAddress="################", 1, 0))
  AS [Number of Errors] 
FROM GPInformation 
WHERE Profile="################" 
   OR Notes="################" 
   OR CriminalConvictionsNotes="################" 
   OR HealthIssueNotes="################" 
   OR NextOfKinAddress="################"
```

I have not tested this code (lacking the immediate facility to do so), but it should work or at least be very close to correct.